# Dimension of intersection of the given subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

My approach:

To find $\dim(W1+W2)$, I use the equation 
$$\dim(W1+W2) = \dim W1 + \dim W2 - \dim(W1 \cap W2)$$

To find $W1 \cap W2$, I simply say that it consists of all the vectors that satisfy both the constraints of $W1$ and $W2$. Hence, I get $\dim = 1$.

Thus, getting $\dim(W1+W2) = 3$. What did I do wrong in the above method?

Comment: Why is $\dim(W_1 + W_2) = 3$ incorrect? It seems correct.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that W1+W2 = R3? That SEEMS incorrect for the above case. Not quite sure though.

Comment: Well, it does imply that $W_1 + W_2 = \mathbb R^3$, which happens to be a true statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dim(W_1+W_3) =3$$ is true and you are write that $W_1+W_2 = \mathbb{R}^3$.

A basis of $W_1$ is $\{(1,0,1), (0,1,1)\}$ and note that $(0,2,1) \in W_2$

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=-1 \ne 0$$

Hence $\{(1,0,1), (0,1,1), (0,2,1)\}$ is a basis of $W_1+W_2 = \mathbb{R}^3$.